# how to map json object having unlimited property to pojo or in @RequestBody variable in controller

Tags: json, spring, mapping, pojo

I have json object as below

```
{'key_1':'value_1','key_2':'value_2','key_3':'value_3',.....'key_N':'value_N',}
```

i tried to map this json with `HashMap<String,String>`, but it does not worked for me.

if any one have solution to map above json with proper datatype in @RequestBody in spirng controller would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That's not valid JSON. And you should use a Map, not a HashMap. If it "doesn't work", then post the code you tried, tell precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Telling us that some unknown code doesn't work is much too vague.

Comment: i tried with ```HashMap<String,String>```  but it is creating only one key value pair.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. And you should use a Map, not a HashMap. If it "doesn't work", then post the code you tried, tell precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Telling us that some unknown code doesn't work is much too vague.

Answer (score -1):

As per question, you can not hold many number of json values in the Map object or any other object because it will become heavy object and may cause memory leaks.

You can add required values to Map or any other object and send response to the client.

Note: it should not be a heavy object because it will impact in the real time environment while concurrency.

However you can use below snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> someMethod(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpSession session) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity;
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        map.put("key3", "value3");
        map.put("key4", "value4");
        map.put("key5", "value5");
        map.put("key6", "value6");
        map.put("key7", "value7");
        map.put("key8", "value8");
        map.put("key9", "value9");
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Object>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: If it not helpful, please send your code which you written so that it can help to give a solution